# Permission denied in install command for Yocto recipes

Tags: permissions, system-installation, yocto

I'm trying to familiarize myself with the Yocto build process and am currently working with recipes. 
I have a very simple recipe

```
DESCRIPTION = "Hello world"

S = "${WORKDIR}"
SRC_URI="file://bye.sh"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${S}/README;md5=e584df0feead52ed7de9b60172adc0cf "

#${D} is /usr and ${bindir} is bin 
    do_install() {
         install  -d /test 
        install -m 0777 bye.sh /test
}
```

i was told that if install doesn't find the directory it will create it for you but in this instance it does not do that! The error it is giving me is

```
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| install: cannot create regular file ‘/usr/bin/bye.sh’: Permission denied
| WARNING: /home/builder/project/runqeme_qemux86/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/directory/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_install.22136:1 exit 1 from 'install -m 0777 bye.sh /usr/bin'
| ERROR: Function failed: do_install (log file is located at /home/builder/project/runqeme_qemux86/build/tmp/work/i586-poky-linux/directory/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.22136)
```

It's not that it can't build a directory there, the recipe refuses to story the bash file anywhere unless it is is in specific directory.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the large but comprehensive *Yocto Reference Manual* and the [simple example](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-single-c-file-package-hello-world) there. It shows a typical install script will move files to a subdirectory of `${D}`, eg

```
install -d ${D}${bindir}
```

You must use a similar tactic, eg `install  -d ${D}/test` and so on.
This variable is explained [here](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.2/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-D).

Read section [5.3.13. Installing](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-installing) for what is expected to happen during the install stage.

Comment: i've read the reference manual and the example they give are rather simple. Originally i was using the "install -d ${D}${bindir}", that's why they are in the comment. The ${D}/test still gives me an error. There is a bitbake.conf file which also told me other directories i could put this in but nothing about making your own directory. Any more suggestions please? I'm really stuck on this issue 
bitbake.conf: http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit.cgi/poky/plain/meta/conf/bitbake.conf?h=blinky

Comment: I found Yocto to be very difficult to understand when you want to do something that does not already have an example you can copy. You must start from a working example and test each tiny single change as you edit it towards your actual needs. Unfortunately, I no longer have access to the recipes I did some years ago, and my notes are not complete. I vaguely remember creating a new top-level directory (your `/test`) requires something more to get in the final image. Try creating your directory as, say, `/usr/bin/mytest` instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I too feel that there is a massive barrier to entry with Yocto. Time and time again i've felt that the manual is "much a do about nothing" I've tried the "/usr/bin/" and even that doesn't seem to have the desired effect only ${D}${bindir} seems to work or any other directory that is defined in bitbake.conf

Answer (score 0):

You do not have permission to create files in your destination directory, which is probably owned by root. Perhaps you can set the `D` variable to somewhere in your home directory, then call `do_install`.

Comment: i don't believe that's the issue because I've tried it on my home directory as well.